# TextBox in MenuItem cannot be edited if it is not empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ContextMenu with MenuItems that I use as a date range selector for standard predefined ranges - Last Week, Last Month, so on. Because the user has to have the option to manually enter any number of days as a date range one of my MenuItems is with a TextBox inside. The entered number of days should be preserved at program exit.

[image]

If the TextBox is empty everything is OK. I can click on it and enter any number inside. Then I click anywhere on the MenuItem or hit the `Enter` key and the `MenuItem.Click` event is fired. After that I can change the number again and again, all is fine.

But if the TextBox is not empty, like when I enter the saved number in the `Loaded` event, then I cannot modify the TextBox content. Click on it only triggers the `MenuItem.Click` event and does not focus on the TextBox itself. I even can't select the number by click-dragging with the mouse.

**XAML:**

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
    <!--Skipped previous items-->
        <MenuItem Header="This Year" Click="menuItemDataRange_Click"
                Tag="{x:Static services:DateRanges.ThisYear}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Last Year" Click="menuItemDataRange_Click"
                Tag="{x:Static services:DateRanges.LastYear}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Tag="" Click="menuItemDataRange_Click">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Last" />
                    <TextBox Width="30" Name="tbCustomDataRange" Margin="2,0" />
                    <Label Content="days" />
                </StackPanel>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

**EDIT:**
I set the content of the TextBox with this line of code, when the in the `Loaded` event. [The UIGlobal is a static class containing utility properties]

```
tbCustomDataRange.Text = UIGlobal.PlayTabCustomDaysCount.ToString();
```

**EDIT2:**
I tried to workaround and do the following. The `MouseEnter` event always gets fired, but if the `Text` property is set with the above line in code or even in XAML the TextBox just doesn't get the focus, or select all content.

```
    private void tbCustomDataRange_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tbCustomDataRange.Focus();
        tbCustomDataRange.SelectAll();
    }
```

Comment: You say "when I enter the saved number on program startup"; can you show us what it looks like in your code when you do that? What do you "enter" the number into on program startup? Do you mean `<TextBox Text="6" />`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing TextBox inside a ContextMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049057/accessing-textbox-inside-a-contextmenu)

Comment: Are you setting the Handled property of the event?  That can disrupt the event routing.

Comment: I am not getting or setting the Handled property anywhere in the code.

Comment: Can you try setting the `Text` property in the `Loaded` event instead of App startup?

Comment: That's exactly where I am setting it

Comment: @mandarin just to be sure... which `Loaded` event are we talking about?

Comment: I can't reproduce this from your description. Can you post the entire XAML and the entire code behind? Incidentally, setting the text in codebehind is the wrong way to do it anyway. You should bind the Text property of that textbox to an int property on your viewmodel. You're fighting XAML every step of the way here. Life is easier if you work with it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it may be, but I think the problem was that no other control was focused previously. At one point I realized that focusing the TextBox was the first thing I was trying to do after the program has started. And if I interacted with any other focusable Control in the Window, Combobox or Button, after that everything was fine with the ContextMenu's TextBox - it gets focused, the text gets selected.

So my workaround is to set my Combobox to be focused `cbProfileSearch.Focus();` in the `Loaded` event and now everything works.

If someone can explain in more detail please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I think the user "Ed Plunkett" is spot on with his comment. Consider programming the WPF way with bindings instead of oldschool value-into-view-pushing.